# How to introspect a Raku operator?

Tags: function, operators, raku

I can introspect routines in Raku, for example the [`say`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/say)
routine:

```
[5] >  &say.WHAT                                                                                                                                                                   
(Sub)
[6] >  &say.^mro                                                                                                                                                                   
((Sub) (Routine) (Block) (Code) (Any) (Mu))
```

but how can I introspect an operator such as `+` ([doc page](https://docs.raku.org/routine/+))?

```
[7] >  &+.WHAT                                                                                                                                                                     
Use of uninitialized value of type Callable in numeric context
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
  in any <main> at /home/toni/.rakubrew/versions/moar-blead/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm line 1
  in any <entry> at /home/toni/.rakubrew/versions/moar-blead/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm line 1

Use of uninitialized value of type Any in numeric context
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
  in any <main> at /home/toni/.rakubrew/versions/moar-blead/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm line 1
  in any <entry> at /home/toni/.rakubrew/versions/moar-blead/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm line 1

[7] >  &+.mro                                                                                                                                                                      
No such method 'mro' for invocant of type 'Any'
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
  in any <main> at /home/toni/.rakubrew/versions/moar-blead/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm line 1
  in any <entry> at /home/toni/.rakubrew/versions/moar-blead/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm line 1
```

Since in Raku, operators are simply [`Sub`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Sub)s after all and thus it's easy to declare new ones, I think I am doing something wrong but I cannot find out what precisely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By trial and error this is what I found:

```
&infix:<+>.WHAT
```

This is what was printed:

```
(Sub+{is-pure}+{Precedence})
```

Comment: For infixes, there is actually a shortcut for that: `&[+].WHAT`

Answer (score 5):

As zentrunix found out, you need both the `&` sigil (which you use to refer to a `Sub` object in general) and the [operator category](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Operator_classification), arranged in the following fashion:

```
&cat:<op>
```

where `cat` is the operator category (e.g., prefix, infix, etc) and `op` is the operator.

For example, the operator `-` has both prefix and infix forms:

```perl
say &infix:<->.WHAT;
say &prefix:<->.WHAT;
```

As you discerned operators in Raku are simply *functions with silly names*¹, thus you could use the `-` operator as follows too:

```perl
say &infix:<->(5, 4); # «1␤»
say &prefix:<->(2);   # «-2␤»
```

❶ I remember reading this somewhere but I cannot recall if it was in the docs or somewhere else.

Comment: ❶ "functions with silly names" Larry called them ["functions with funny names and syntax"](https://design.raku.org/S01.html#:~:text=Operators%20are%20just%20functions%20with%20funny%20names%20and%20syntax.). I think the "funny" is one third a Wally pun ("funny" ≈ "functiony"), two thirds [a reasonable use of one of the meanings of "funny" as "strange or odd"](https://www.google.com/search?q=funny&rlz=1C1CHZN_enGB970GB971&oq=funny&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i433i512j0i512j0i433i512l2j69i61l3.2740j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#:~:text=difficult%20to%20explain%20or%20understand%3B%20strange%20or%20odd.).